# How to add several values to the same key

Tags: ruby

how can I add several values to the same key? Something like this:

```
x = {}
x["k1"] =  nil
x["k1"] << {"a" => "a"}
x["k1"] << {"b" => "b"}
```

well, this doesn't work like with array.

Comment: If you think about a multi-value key-value pair as nothing more than a key to a set of key-value pairs, then you can imagine how to achieve the kind of mapping that you're looking for in regards to typical modern hash notation. Instead of `{:key => value1,value2}`, think `{:key => [{:subkey_1 => value_1},{:subkey_2 => value_2}]}` -- that's what you can do in Ruby, at least.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do as below :

For `Array` as value to the key of a `Hash` :

```
h = Hash.new{|hsh,key| hsh[key] = [] }
h['k1'].push 'a'
h['k1'].push 'b'
p h # >> {"k1"=>["a", "b"]}
```

For `Hash` as value to the key of a `Hash` :

```
h = Hash.new{|hsh,key| hsh[key] = {} }
h['k1'].store 'a',1
h['k1'].store 'b',1
p h # >> {"k1"=>{"a"=>1, "b"=>1}}
```

Comment: Recomend for this code, is more simple `h['k1'] << 'a' << 'b'`

Answer (score 6):

Depends on just what you're trying to accomplish here.  If you want a hash of arrays, that's easy enough:

```
x = {}
x['k1'] = Array.new
x['k1'] << 'a'
x['k1'] << 'b'
```

or if you want nested hashes, simple enough as well

```
x = {}
x['k1'] = {}
x['k1']['a'] = 'a'
x['k1']['b'] = 'b'
```

the values in a hash are just objects.  They can be arrays, other hashes, or whatever else you might want.

Answer (score 3):

So, you want the value of key 'k1' to be a hash, and you want to add key/value pairs to that hash. You can do it like this:

```
2.0.0-p195 :111 > x = {}
 => {} 
2.0.0-p195 :112 > x['k1'] = { 'a' => '1' }
 => {"a"=>"1"} 
2.0.0-p195 :117 > x['k1'].merge!({ 'b' => '2' })
 => {"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"}
```

Or, you can do it like this:

```
2.0.0-p195 :119 > x['k1']['c'] = 3
 => 3 
2.0.0-p195 :120 > x['k1']
 => {"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>3}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't: a hash key has only one value by definition. 
In addition, you are trying to use the shovel operator `<<`, an array method, to set the value. But even if you used `=`, every time you set the key to a new value, the old value is lost:

```
x = {}
=> {} 
x["k1"] = {"a" => "a"}
=> {"a"=>"a"}
x["k1"] = {"b" => "b"}
=> {"b"=>"b"}
```

As others have pointed out, if you want "several values" per key, you should use some kind of collection

```
x = {}
=> {} 
x["k1"] = {"a" => "a", "b" => "b"}
=> {"a"=>"a", "b"=>"b"}
```